# Jupyter Notebook - Can't Load Installed Package

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

In a Jupyter Notebook (but also in Python cmd line and IPython), I'm trying to load an package that is already installed on my system:

```
!pip install pymysql
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy

Requirement already satisfied: pymysql in /Users/testuser/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.0.2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-027efe73a901> in <module>
     19 # required for the database connection
     20 get_ipython().system('pip install pymysql')
---> 21 import pymysql
     22 import sqlalchemy
```

I'm sure this is pretty basic stuff, but I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have several python versions installed and you pip did not install the package on the one you use

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed the `pymysql` library in virtual environment.

You need to install `pymysql` outside of virtual environment.

Try opening a command prompt and use `pip install pymysql` without activating any virtual command